# java HashMap key swap during get()

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

In a usage case, I have a HashMap which contains 1 entry and the key is A. I need to call get() with key B many many times. A equals() to B but A and B are not the same object. The Key  contains a long array so its equals() is expensive. I am trying to improve the performance for this map checking operation. I know there are proper ways to address the performance issue. However, I am considering a hack which is the most expedient.

The following is from HashMap.java:

```
    public V get(Object key) {
        if (key == null)
            return getForNullKey();
        int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
             e != null;
             e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
                return e.value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

if i change the if block in the for loop to:

```
        if (e.hash == hash) {
            if (e.key == key) {
                return e.value; 
            } else if (e.key.equals(key)) {
                e.key = (K) key;
                return e.value;
            }
        }
```

I think it will help the performance a lot. The first time I call get() with key B, B's equals() will be called. For the rest of times, B will be == to the key in the map thus saves the equals() call.

However, it is not possible to just extend HashMap and override get() since HashMap.field is package protected and Entry.key is final.

Questions:

1. Will this scheme work?
2. Copying HashMap.java and its related code just to change one method is not very appealing. What is the best way to implement this hack?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a hashmap with only one entry?

Comment: It happens to be the case. However, I guess it doesn't matter. It can contains more entries and I think my approach should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this should work, if `equals` is implemented properly (symmetric).

Try to hack `equals` method in the class of your map's keys:

```
equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) return false;
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    if (this.longArray == other.longArray) return true;
    if (Arrays.equals(this.longArray, other.longArray)) {
        this.longArray = other.longArray;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since your class is immutable, this trick should be safe. Your should make `longArray` field non-final, but it won't hurt performance, I promise.

Comment: If this is to be used in multi-threaded code, `final` could be replaced with `volatile`, to avoid synchronization, since this should also be the only mutation to `longArray` in the whole class (besides constructors).

Comment: @leventov, I appreciate your help. I think it will work. I initially want to hack the map instead of key to the map since the map will be discard once out of scope. Key will be changed for ever. Although changing key should be just fine, I feel less guilty if my hack is  temporary. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @user3258744 we can't invent a solution from the air.  Change key class or copy `HashMap` with your modification. I don't see any other abilities.

Comment: @afsantos I really couldn't imagine why `longArray` replacement should be synchronized in any way. State doesn't change.

Comment: @leventov Since the arrays are equal, state doesn't change when replacing one for the other. But the synchronization provided by `volatile` guarantees that no thread will hold references to the old copy of the array, thus making the old array eligible for garbage collection. Other than that, I can't imagine any advantages either.

Comment: @afsantos no thread will hold reference to the old copy forever. The old copy will be collected sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

This is a horrible idea. You are mutating an entry's key under the covers.

The solution is to create your own internal "identity hash value", something you can calculate and guarantee is unique for each value.  Then use this as a proxy for the expensive comparison in your `equals()` method.

For example (pseudo-Java):

```
class ExpensiveEquals
{
    private class InxpensiveEqualsIdentity
    {
        ...
        public InexpensiveEqualsIdentity(ExpensiveEquals obj) { ... }
        public boolean equals() { an inexpensive comparison }
    }
    private InxpensiveEqualsIdentity identity;
    public ExpensiveEquals(...)
    {
        ... fill in the object
        this.identity = new InexpensiveEqualsIdentity(this);
    }
    public int hashCode() { return this.identity.hashCode(); }
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || !o instanceof this.getClass()) return false;
        return (this.identity.equals(((ExpensiveEquals)o).identity));
    }
}
```

Comment: First, the keys in my case are immutable. I am not changing any objects here. I merely replace an object in HashMap with another object that equals() the original one. If this corrupts the map, how so?
Second, the performance issue I have is because A and B are equals and it is the equals() that is expensive. Caching hashCode values won't help.

Comment: The point is it's completely unnecessary to do this. Just implement  `hashCode()` to return the same value for both `A` and `B`, which it must do to satisfy its contract... `equals()` will never be invoked.

Comment: The performance problem is in the equals(). The equals() is called only if hash codes are the same.

Comment: Ah, I slightly misunderstood your question.  Add to the class of `A` and `B` your own identity hash that you can guarantee is unique and use that for identity management in `equals()`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make it clear. A and B are instances of the same class. A.equals(B) == true. There are many different instances serialized in from different places and they all equals(). I could implement a singleton logic in the readObject() so that objects serialized in will become the same singleton, but its impact is bigger and other part of the code will pay the penalty even if they don't care about equals().

Comment: I stand by @JimGarrison 's answer. If your keys have an expensive `equals()` method, the problem is not in the `HashMap` code, but in the design choices that led to using them as keys in a map. You can hack it but that will lead to maintaining a parallel version of the collection which is a bad idea.

Comment: As I stated in my original question, I know this is a hack. I know this is caused by bad design. However, sometimes it just ain't easy to start a revolution:)
BTW, can somebody elaborate on @JimGarrison's answer? I don't understand the details.

Comment: Jim, I appreciate your code example. The problem is that it is not possible to write an inexpensive equals(), at least not before calling equals() inside a hashmap. The expensive part is the long array comparison. I want to exploit the fact that most of the long arrays to be compared are the same object. Thus == will improve performance drastically.

Answer (score 0):

If `B` is the key you are really interested in, you can just perform the swap from the outside.

```
V val = map.remove(b);
map.put(b, val);
```

From then on, reference equality is sufficient for `B` but you aren't futzing with the internal mechanism.

Comment: The problems of this approach is that I can't detect the case and calling remove() and put() will call equals() more times. I only want to swap when A.equals(B) but A != B with minimum penalty.

Answer (score 0):

My simple lazy idea built on top of @JimGarrison's answer:

```
private long hash0, hash1;

void initHash() {
    // Compute a hash using md5 and store it in hash0 and hash1
    // The collision probability for two objects is 2**-128, i.e., very small,
    //   and grows with the square of the number of objects.
    // Use SHA-1 if you're scared.
}

void assureHash() {
    if (hash0 == 0 && hash1 == 0) initHash();
}


public int hashCode() {
    // If both hashes are zero, assume it wasn't computed yet.
    assureHash();
    return (int) hash0;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof ExpensiveEquals)) return false;
    ExpensiveEquals that = (ExpensiveEquals) o;
    this.assureHash();
    that.assureHash();
    return this.hash0 == that.hash0 && this.hash1 == that.hash1;
}
```

This ensures that all equals invocations but the first will be pretty cheap. The changes that two randomly chosen pairs of longs are equals are negligible even when assuming thousands of objects and taking the birthday paradox into account. With a cryptographic hash function the numbers are as good as random.

If md5 and two `long`s aren't good enough, use SHA-1 and one additional `int` (that's what `git` does).